# How to convert an Iterator[String] to Reader[String]?

Tags: parsing, scala

I'm trying to parse a file line-by-line using parser combinators. It's clear for me how to write the parsers themselves, but when to run them I have to provide an `Input` = `Reader[String]`. Given that I have an `Iterator[String]` reading the file (or a `Source`), what is the best way to run it through parsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up implementing.

```
class BufferingReader(iterator: Iterator[String], val position: Int) extends Reader[String] {
    def this(iterator: Iterator[String]) = this(iterator, 0)

    val _atEnd = !iterator.hasNext
    val _first = if (!_atEnd) iterator.next else "<THIS SHOULD NEVER BE READ>"
    lazy val _rest = new BufferingReader(iterator, position + 1)

    def atEnd = _atEnd
    def first = _first
    def rest = _rest

    def pos = new Position { def line = position; def column = 0; def lineContents = _first }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I parse files this way:

```
parsers.parseAll(parser, FileReader("foo.bar"))
```

But I bet this does not close the file properly. [`FileReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) is a Java class and there is one version of `parseAll`, which accepts `java.io.Reader`. This is really not easy to extract from the API docs...

Further research shows that there exists [`def apply (in: Reader): StreamReader`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.parsing.input.StreamReader$) in `StreamReader` which can be used to manually convert a Java `Reader`.

#### Edit

If you really parse something else than a sequence of Char, well, then my answer doesn't apply. From skipping through the docs, it seems that you have to roll your own `Reader`, as all concrete subclasses of `Reader` seem to be specialized to Char.

Comment: Wouldn't that return a `Reader[Char]`?

Comment: @huynhjl It works in the most normal sense that I can imagine. Maybe if your parser accepts String tokens, something else would be better.

Comment: Closing `StreamReader` will close `FileReader`. Java guarantees that.

Comment: What is that `FileReader`? I can't find it in the API.

Comment: Also, I can't find `parseAll` in `Parsers`, only in `RegexParsers` that are specialized for `Char` only. What kind of `Parsers` do you use?

Comment: @FixPoint Uh, so you really parse something else than a sequence of `Char`? Well, then my answer doesn't apply. From skipping through the docs, it seems that you have to roll your own, then as all subclasses of `Reader` seem to be specialized to `Char`.

Comment: @ziggystar Yes, I'm parsing with `type Elem = String`, that's why I've used `[String]` parameterization in the question.

Comment: @Fixpoint I thought you don't know what you're doing. Because getting an `Iterator[String]` from a `Source.getLines` doesn't mean you have to parse with `String` as `Elem`.